# how to fix docker: 'daemon' is not a docker command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-daemon

[my issue's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhQLY.png)

**harivinu01@penguin:~$** sudo dockerd
INFO[2022-10-11T11:09:00.045076001+05:30] Starting up
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
**harivinu01@penguin:~$**

Comment: docker is a service and should be started and stopped accordingly: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-discover/2.0.3?topic=ni-multi-node-network-settings-get-stuck-while-checking-docker-run-status

Answer (score 0):

have you tried kill docker process or restart?

Comment: how to do that, can you please write command for kill and restart. I'm beginner to docker

Comment: I mean restart machine

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the pid file

```
ps -ef | grep docker
kill -9 <PIDs>
```

2. Kill the docker service and start it again

```
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Comment: it's not working, still i'm facing the same problem.     harivinu01@penguin:~$ sudo dockerd
INFO[2022-10-11T12:27:31.785688981+05:30] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid